# Changing the background color of html buttons forward and backward after clicks

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScipt and HTML and only need it as a side issue. I have some buttons and I want their backround color to change after clicked. That I could solve partly with:

```html
<input class="choice" onclick="this.style.background='blue';" type="submit" value='V' id='0' />
```

However, when the button is clicked a second time it should change back. Preferably would be a one line statement like above. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: how is it supposed to be clicked again if it gets disabled?

Comment: Are you trying to get the button enabled on second click? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: @nicael Sry, forgot to take this out here. I should be without the `this.disabled=true`.

Comment: Edited to remove this.disabled=true; per the user's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke your code out into seperate JS, it's cleaner that way and easier to maintain.

If you disable the button, then it stops recieving click events. I assume that's not what you want.

Here, I've made it so that when the button is clicked, it toggles the background color between red and blue.

http://jsbin.com/huqoyixuhe/edit?html,css,js,output

```
// select the button
var input = document.querySelector('input.choice');
// add a click event listener
input.addEventListener('click', function () {
  // if the button is red, make it blue
  if (this.style.background === 'red') {
    this.style.background = 'blue';
  }
  // otherwise, it is already blue, so make it red! 
  else {
    this.style.background = 'red';
  }


});
```

**EDIT**

here, as a one-liner:
http://jsbin.com/bolowuceqa/edit?html,output

```
<input class="choice" onclick="this.style.background==='red' ? this.style.background = 'blue' : this.style.background = 'red'" style="background:red;" type="submit" value='V' id='0' />
```

Comment: Thx, but are u sure it's working? For me the button just stays red. Isn't there any "one line solution"? I would prefer that, because the html document that contains these buttons will be build up with some template engine (jinja2) and, so far, I have trouble inserting JavaScript functions in that. I also can't import a JavaScript file. It has to be written already within the html document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggole between class Name through pure javascript.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="toggole" class="red" onclick="toggolecolor()">
Click Please
</button>
```

**CSS:**.red{

```
  background-color:red;
}
.blue{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function toggolecolor(){
 var element = document.getElementById("toggole");
  element.classList.toggle("red");
    element.classList.toggle("blue");

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<body bgcolor="(color)"/>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that this is not valid html. You need to close the tags correctly. For example `</head>` is missing. Also `bgcolor` is deprecated  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/bgColor. Besides, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer